# How to get frequent background GPS updates in Codename One?

Tags: android, ios, gps, codenameone

I'm writing an app that requires frequent location checks using GPS. It needs to get the current location every 10-15 seconds and then write it to a database (the database part is mostly irrelevant for this question, just wanted to throw it out there). The issue I'm facing is that I can't find a decent way to accomplish this. I've tried several things:

1. Using `LocationManager.getBackgroundLocationListener()` never seems to work. I've tried it on both Android and iOS and nothing ever seems to happen. Might be something I'm doing wrong but regardless, I've read that on iOS, it will only get hit when moving to a different cell tower, so that doesn't meet my needs.
2. I've tried using Background Fetch, but it's only reliable on Android. The frequency is completely random on iOS and so this won't meet my needs either.
3. I've tried just starting a new thread that will fetch the current location every 10-15 seconds, but this only works when the screen is on and the app is being used. This won't meet my needs because I need to make sure it continues getting location updates when switching to other apps.

Does anyone have any suggestions on alternative methods to solve this problem? Note that I don't have a background in objective-c, so a cross-platform solution like Codename One is really my only option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background fetch isn't the right choice in this case as iOS expects you to declare what you are actually doing. What you are trying to do is prohibited in iOS and might be problematic in Android too.

Fetching location data in the background (especially at this resolution) has serious privacy implications so I doubt it will work. Doing this in the foreground should work fine to allow use cases such as navigation but in the background it might be an issue.

This is further compounded by the fact that location and networking are big battery draining activities. So there are limits to the resolution you can apply with these API's. One of the more common use cases for background is geo-fencing which allows you to track when a user approaches an important point of interest. The reason this API exists is to reduce polling costs and keep location usage to a minimum.

Notice that both Android & iOS provide tools to detect battery usage for the user and these might impact misbehaving apps.

Comment: Thanks Shai, very helpful.  Seems iOS is too restrictive for this app at this time.  I've already released it as an Android-only app so I guess it will remain that way for now.  I really like CN1.  If I write another app, one that doesn't rely on background data, I'll be sure to use it in the future.

Comment: Just so we are clear those limitations are derived from native and unrelated to Codename One. If you will explain what you are trying to accomplish with the app it's possible Apple has a workaround for that use case.